# Passing C# attributes to onChange event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to pass C# attributes that are initiated inside an html page, here's how it looks:

the C# code inside the page:

```
var user = DataAccess.GetById(signIn.GetUserId(User));
var username = user.Username;
var password = user.Password;
```

then I have a dropdown with options and I want that when I user picks something it will fire off an event and pass in the username and password to that event, here's how it looks:

```
<select id="userServicesDropDownAuth" class="browser-default custom-select" asp-for="Service" onchange="validateUserAuth(this, @username, @password)">
    @{
        <option style="display:none"></option>
        foreach (var item in services)
        {
            <option>@item.ToString()</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

the username and password are initiated before this method is reached, but for some reason, it won't fire it off, only if I take the @ away from the attributes they will fire off but will be undefined of course.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing your parameters as objects. Just add quotes to your method call to pass it as string.

```
validateUserAuth(this, '@username', '@password')
```